# Bald patch on stray cat's neck, what should I do?

Tags: cats, skin-condition, veterinarian, strays, hairloss

So there is a stray cat I've been feeding for a few weeks now and he has a bald patch. He didn't have it when I first saw him and I think it began or happened pretty recently. It's on his neck so I don't think he did it by over grooming or by biting himself or something. Please tell me what it actually is and what I should do. It looks like this:

[image][image]

Comment: Have you ever found out what it was? To me it looks like the hair fell out after a bite of a tick. The tick bite probably got infected and then the hair fell out. It will grow back.

Comment: I was wondering if you received an answer? I have a stray cat I take care off who also has a bold spot like that in his neck. First I was wondering if it was ringworm but maybe Tim is right and it was a tick?